# Xperia XZ1 - impossible to access bootloader after factory reset

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, lineageos, sony-xperia

I have this Xperia XZ1 which I unlocked the bootloader in the past to install custom Lineage through TWRP. As the distro wasn't working correctly with my carrier I reseted it to an official one.

Recently I did a factory reset and now, when I try to access the bootloader, for example to access TWRP to install Lineage, it seems there isn't any recovery boot available anymore.

When I start with power button + volume up, I get 3 vibrations and then nothing happens. When I start with power button + volume down it keeps restarting. When I access flash mode, through volume up + usb cable, I get the blue led but from there I can not do much with fastboot, trying to upload twrp results in nothing happening terminal wise.

Any idea where the recovery mode is or how to access it ? It feels the recovery mode disappeared from the phone.